# Move to next item using Java 8 foreach loop in stream

Tags: java, java-8

I have a problem with the stream of Java 8 foreach attempting to move on next item in loop. I cannot set the command like `continue;`, only `return;` works but you will exit from the loop in this case. I need to move on next item in loop. How can I do that?

Example(not working):

```
try(Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)){
            filteredLines = lines.filter(...).foreach(line -> {
           ...
           if(...)
              continue; // this command doesn't working here
    });
}
```

Example(working):

```
try(Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)){
    filteredLines = lines.filter(...).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

for(String filteredLine : filteredLines){
   ...
   if(...)
      continue; // it's working!
}
```

Comment: I need to move on next item in loop.

Comment: His point is, with the code you've shown, not having the `continue` would still move onto the next item without any functional changes anyway.

Comment: If the goal is to avoid executing lines coming after the call to continue, and that you're not showing us, just put all these lines in an `else` block. If there is nothing after `continue`, then drop the if block and the continue: they're useless.

Answer (score 453, accepted):

Using `return;` will work just fine.  It will not prevent the full loop from completing.  It will only stop executing the current iteration of the `forEach` loop.

Try the following little program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
    stringList.add("a");
    stringList.add("b");
    stringList.add("c");

    stringList.stream().forEach(str -> {
        if (str.equals("b")) return; // only skips this iteration.

        System.out.println(str);
    });
}
```

Output:

> a
>   c

Notice how the `return;` is executed for the `b` iteration, but `c` prints on the following iteration just fine.

### Why does this work?

The reason the behavior seems unintuitive at first is because we are used to the `return` statement interrupting the execution of the whole method.  So in this case, we expect the `main` method execution as a whole to be halted.

However, what needs to be understood is that a lambda expression, such as:

```
str -> {
    if (str.equals("b")) return;

    System.out.println(str);
}
```

... really needs to be considered as its own distinct "method", completely separate from the `main` method, despite it being conveniently located within it. So really, the `return` statement only halts the execution of the lambda expression.

The second thing that needs to be understood is that:

```
stringList.stream().forEach()
```

... is really just a normal loop under the covers that executes the lambda expression for every iteration.

With these 2 points in mind, the above code can be rewritten in the following equivalent way (for educational purposes only):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
    stringList.add("a");
    stringList.add("b");
    stringList.add("c");

    for(String s : stringList) {
        lambdaExpressionEquivalent(s);
    }
}

private static void lambdaExpressionEquivalent(String str) {
    if (str.equals("b")) {
        return;
    }

    System.out.println(str);
}
```

With this "less magic" code equivalent, the scope of the `return` statement becomes more apparent.

Answer (score 8):

Another solution: go through a filter with your inverted conditions :
Example :

```
if(subscribtion.isOnce() && subscribtion.isCalled()){
                continue;
}
```

can be replaced with

```
.filter(s -> !(s.isOnce() && s.isCalled()))
```

The most straightforward approach seem to be using "return;" though.

Answer (score 2):

The lambda you are passing to `forEach()` is evaluated for each element received from the stream.  The iteration itself is not visible from within the scope of the lambda, so you cannot `continue` it as if `forEach()` were a C preprocessor macro.  Instead, you can conditionally skip the rest of the statements in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `if` statement instead of continue. So instead of the way you have your code, you can try:

```
try(Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)){
            filteredLines = lines.filter(...).foreach(line -> {
           ...
           if(!...) {
              // Code you want to run
           }
           // Once the code runs, it will continue anyway
    });
}
```

The predicate in the if statement will just be the opposite of the predicate in your `if(pred) continue;` statement, so just use `!` (logical not).

Answer (score 0):

you can use `takeWhile` lambda function.

> Returns, if this stream is ordered, a stream consisting of the longest prefix of elements taken from this stream that match the given predicate. Otherwise returns, if this stream is unordered, a stream consisting of a subset of elements taken from this stream that match the given predicate.

```
public class TestFilterLoop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
        stringList.add("a");
        stringList.add("b");
        stringList.add("c");
        stringList.add("d");

        stringList.stream()
                .takeWhile(str -> !str.equals("c"))
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

prints only until the string is not `c`. So it will return and not continue the loop. Output:

```
a
b
```