# continue doesn't work when using streams and the map

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, java-8, java-stream

I have this simple code where I use a stream and a .map() function. 
I do a null check for the id, and inside it a add a **continue**
The continue gives me an error: ***Continue outside of loop***
When I remove the continue I don't get an error, but I don't know if the behaviour is the same?

```
public List<Long> getIds(final Long[][] value){
     List<Long> list = Arrays.stream(value).map(result ->{
                final Long id = result[1];
                if(id == null){
                    continue; // This part doesn't work (error: Continue outside of loop)
                }
                return id;
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Any suggestion on why this happens with .streams? Whereas, when I don't use the stream I can use **continue**.

The question has been marked as duplicate, but it's not the case. Using `return` surely works in `forEach`, where no return type is requested, but not in `map`.

Comment: @snnguyen in a `map` function? I don't think so

Comment: @snnguyen I saw that question, I tried just `return;` it didn't actually work

Comment: Of course it doesn't work... `map` needs the function to return something.

Comment: @Andronicus i totally misread the question

Comment: `Arrays.stream(value).map(result -> result[1]).filter(Objects::notNull).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: @JoopEggen the `notNull` gives me the error: **Cannot resolve method 'notNull'**

Comment: @dernor00 For clarity you would need to share the type of  `value` in the question.

Comment: @Naman I eddited the question, the value is any value of type Long[][]. Sorry I forgot to add that...

Comment: dernor00 -  Glad you did, and you can simply use `map` as stated by @JoopEggen. Just a minor correction there would be using **`nonNull`** instead of    `notNull` with the complete implementation looking like `public static List<Long> getIds(final Long[][] value) {
        return Arrays.stream(value)
                .map(result -> result[1]) // AIOBE possible!!
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }`

Comment: You just needed a filter for not null

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`continue` works in a for loop. You can use `flatMap` as a workaround:

```
 List<Long> list = Arrays.stream(value).flatMap(result ->{
            final Long id = result[1];
            return Stream.ofNullable(id);
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can also make it more concise by using `Stream.ofNullable` directly as @Naman suggests:

```
 List<Long> list = Arrays.stream(value)
    .flatMap(result -> Stream.ofNullable(result[1]))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The other, more elegant version of my firstly proposed method by @Holger would be to use the predicate in the `filter`:

```
 List<Long> list = Arrays.stream(value)
    .map(result -> result[1])
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I get this error when I use Stream: **Incompatible types. Required List<Long> but 'collect' was inferred to R: no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that Stream<?> conforms to Long inference variable T has incompatible bounds: equality constraints: Long lower bounds: Stream<?>**

Comment: Though `Stream.ofNullable` in the `flatMap` (with Java-9) would improve the readability of the code. I don't understand, what's the harm in mapping and filtering instead as pointed out in one of the comments? I believe that would be much cleaner still.

Comment: @dernor00 Can you provide the `value` variable?

Comment: @Andronicus yes

Comment: @Naman you're right, I didn't notice that. Nice catch, thank you!

Comment: @Andronicus  I edited my question, I added the whole method. The value will be of type Long[][]

Comment: @dernor00 how do I say that without sounding like a programmer? It works for me:
`List<Long> list = Arrays.stream(new Long[][]{{1L, 2L},{3L, 4L}}).flatMap(result ->{
            final Long id = result[1];
            return Stream.ofNullable(id);
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
`

Comment: @Andronicus thank you, I know know where my mistake with that error was. It was because I forgot to use .flatMap() but I keept the .map(). Now it works with your old and new version :)

Comment: ..or further simple `.flatMap(result -> Stream.ofNullable(result[1]))`

Comment: @Naman I thought about it, but I wanted to show the answer with `return` keyword, just like the answer marked as duplicate for `forEach`

Comment: What’s the advantage of “show the answer with return keyword”? It’s just a verbose version of `.flatMap(result -> Stream.ofNullable(result[1]))`. So why not use @Naman’s Java 8 compatible `.map(a -> a[1]).filter(Objects::nonNull)`…

Comment: @Holger I just wanted to reference the question marked as duplicate where the accepted answer uses `return` to skip the loop, but I added this more elegant version as a side note, thank you

Comment: Well, in your solution, `return` doesn’t act as a “skip the loop”. Besides that, using `if(condition) return;` in a `forEach` is non-idiomatic. People who prefer this coding style should stay with a loop. You should rather try to match [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45057964/2711488)…

Comment: @Holger you're right that is more accurate. I hope it's ok, that I reference your suggestion in the answer?

Comment: That’s what comments are for. But note that I use `map` before `filter` to avoid a redundant `result[1]`.

Comment: @Holger and once again you're right. I might be too tired not to see those things. Thank you:)